# Change Solr search directory to my custom named index directory

Tags: solr, lucene

In the /data directory of solr, suppose, I have three folders named as index, custom, spellCheck.
So, the problem is when I open up localhost:8983/solr/admin and try to search, solr makes a search only in the index folder. I want solr to search in the 'custom' folder inside the /data folder. 
Can it be done?

If I see the 'schema browser', and go through the schema information, there is a 'directory' property
such as,
directory:  org.apache.lucene.store.NIOFSDirectory:org.apache.lucene.store.NIOFSDirectory@ ***/home/mypc/softwares/apache-solr-3.4.0/example/solr/data/index*** lockFactory=org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLockFactory@6c5482

I think that /solr/data/index directory should point to /solr/data/custom, for the search to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use the index.properties file to point to which directory Solr loads. It goes in the data directory and it has a index property pointing to the directory name to be used instead of 'index'

That's worked for me without issue. I believe this was done to help make replication work seamlessly.

Comment: That's cool!...thanks for the trick :) But how is it related to replication? I may be wrong but isn't Solr replication like copying the indexes from a master to a different machine?

Comment: When the replication happens, the index is put into a index.$timestamp directory in case something goes wrong and you have to revert to the former index. My understanding is that the index.properties file is updated on completion and is picked up when the slave is committed.

Answer (score 1):

Solr uses index directory as the fixed name, so i don't think it can be customized unless you modified the code.

```
solr.core.dataDir -- The core's data directory (i.e. the directory under which that core's index directory are located)
```

If you need the search to work only on the custom directoy, you can try creating a symlink.

Comment: So, is there any way I could merge or bring my 'custom' dir contents or segments inside the index folder once it is created? Actually my problem is I have few already created index folders such as custom1, custom2, custom3...n, so would like to merge all in one 'index' folder. I think that's possible, isn't it?

Comment: you can create cores for each of your custom folders. Rename the folder names to index so its the official index contents folder. When you have these cores use the merge command to combine all cores into to create a single core @ http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin#MERGEINDEXES